# Distributed transaction completed. Either enlist this session in a new transaction or the NULL transaction. After the first Scope.complete()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-sql-database, distributed-transactions

I'm working with Azure ServiceBus and i have a queue with several requests, i read the queue, get the data and do some logic. The problem starts when i have more than 1 request in the queue, the first one works fine, but the second one give me this Exception: Distributed transaction completed. Either enlist this session in a new transaction or the NULL transaction.

I read about Distributed Transaction and it is used when there are more than 1 DataBase and this is not my case, so i dont know why i'm getting this error.

Here is my code.

```
    public async Task Save(ObjectDto objectQueueDto)
    {
        try
        {
            Object object = await GetByCode(objectQueueDto.code); // Here i get the error in the second request that come from the ServiceBus queue
            
            //Some validations

            using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
            {
                // Insert and Update several tables.
                
                scope.Complete();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AppLogger.Instance().Exception(ex);
            throw new FallaTecnicaException(ex.Message, ex);
        }
    }
```

I'm working with EF Core 2.2, .NET core 2.2 and Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8 .

**EDIT**

Here is the GetByCode method

```
    public async Task<Object> GetByCode(string code)
    {
        try
        {
            return await this.DatosUow.Object
                .FindByCondition(w => w.code == code)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AppLogger.Instance().Exception(ex);
            throw new DataException(ex.Message, ex);
        }
    }
```

This is how the inserts methods looks like

```
    public async Task<Object> Save(Object object)
    {
        try
        {
            this.DatosUow.Object.Add(object);
            await this.DatosUow.Object.SaveChangesAsync();

            return object;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AppLogger.Instance().Exception(ex);
            throw new DataException(ex.Message, ex);
        }
    }
```

And This is how the Update methods looks like

```
    public async Task<Object> Update(Object object)
    {
        try
        {
            this.DatosUow.Object.Update(object);
            await this.DatosUow.Object.SaveChangesAsync();

            return object;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AppLogger.Instance().Exception(ex);
            throw new DataException(ex.Message, ex);
        }
    }
```

I'm using the UOW pattern to manage the access data.

Comment: Can you share what is happening in the GetByCode method, especially is if is also making database calls? Depending on how it is setup, if could be causing issues even if it is calling the same database.

You may have have a reason for managing transactions yourself, but if not, you may want to avoid using TransactionScope and just using the transactions that EF creates whenever you call SaveChanges().

Comment: @SamaraSoucy-MSFT Done

Comment: Thank you. My first guess is a conflict between queries that use TransactionScope and those that don't, but I'll try to repro it to be sure.

Comment: I've tried quite a few different scenarios based on this code and I'm not able to replicate it. If you are still having this issue and have an Azure support plan I'd suggest opening a ticket. If you don't have a support plan, you can send me an email at azcommunity(at)microsoft.com with your subscription Id and a link to this thread and I will enable your subscription for a one-time free support ticket.

Comment: Hi @SamaraSoucy-MSFT, thanks for your support, i'm gonna work in my software structure to see if i have something wrong or something that help me to solve this problem. If i'm not able to resolve the error i'm going to send you the email. Thanks and regardings from Colombia.

Comment: Np. There's a lot of factors and it's difficult to reproduce every one without the actual code. Something that may help is that `new TransactionScope()` doesn't mean you are creating a new transaction- the transaction manager decides whether or not to do that. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscope?view=netcore-3.1#remarks If takes more management in your code, but using EF's `context.Database.BeginTransaction()` may avoid the issue completely.